# /admin/dashboard not found in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-backpack

I am facing a problem while working on Laravel backpack as after logging in my page is redirected to the dashboard but It says 404 Not found. So can any one please solve this problem, why this problem occurs as I did not changed much on the code.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: We need to see the code... Could you please add your routes.php?

Answer (score 1):

I know this one. 
This is kind of an issue, because it's hardcoded in vendor. We are working to fix it.

Go to app/Http/Controller/Auth/LoginController.php and check the constructor. It should look similar to this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->loginPath = config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/login';
    $this->redirectTo = config('backpack.base.route_prefix');
    $this->redirectAfterLogout = '/';
}
```

Then go to config/backpack/base and change the route prefix. Let me know it it worked. If this does not solve the issue please paste the two files I mentioned.